# Html pattern just 10 digit

Tags: html, regex, pattern-matching

I have tried to restrict users in HTML number input to insert 10 digit number and should start with 0

```
<input type="number" pattern="^\d{10}$">
```

when user insert 10 digit that is not start with 0 it work but when first digit is 0 it not work

```
1234567891 it works

0123456789 it not works
```

Comment: Is that leading zero actually surviving after you enter it into your input form?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="num" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required>
</form>
```

Comment: It should start with zero

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input type="text" name="num"  pattern="[0]{1}[0-9]{9}">
```